# Como puedo desactivar una casilla de checbox justo despues de que chekeo otra?

Tags: android-studio, checkbox

Tengo un activity donde deseo seleccionar si el genero es masculino o femenino, para ello tengo dos checbox. Como puedo hacer para que al marcar, por ejemplo en femenino automaticamente se me desactive la casilla de masculino para que no puedan ser seleccionadas las dos opciones?

Comment: Usa RadioButton y usa un RadioGroup para agrupar los elementos y automáticamente solo uno podrá ser seleccionado.

Comment: Si. Creo que es la única forma . Bueno muchas gracias.

Comment: Está bien explicado [en la documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton), e incluye código de ejemplo.